# C# + sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Народ, решил заморочиться и связаться с sqlite. Просто сейчас пишу на шарпе, но потом думаю портировать базу на андроид, а там sqlite. Подскажите, с чего начать. Скачал какой-то нативный драйвер для sqlite в ньюгете (вс 2010), но вот в поставщиках данных sqlite не появился. Может, что не так делаю.

И сразу следующий вопрос: с помощью чего можно редактироват бд sqlite? В оигинале было бы зашибись связка uml редактор -> код для sqlite -> прикурутить бд sqlite к проекту. Кто сталкивался\знает, подскажите, плиз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все очень просто http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2014/12/c-sqlite.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще этот материал почитать [VS 2010 + SQLite](http://forums.udove.ru/index.php?topic=46.msg856#msg856)